# PHP ssh2_connect via proxy

Tags: php, http, ssh, proxy, http-proxy

Is there any solution to user ssh2_connect(host,port) via campany proxy ?

i think ssh2_connect not include connection via HTTP PROXY

thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a tip to skip the corporate http proxy when you developpe,

What we need : a server who has access to the source and ssh access

open tunnel from this server like this :

```
ssh -L 9999:server_probleme_access:PORT name_server_access_srouce@IP
```

after you juste call http://127.0.0.1:9999 and you will have access

Hope this help